# How to join one-to-zero-or-one relation?

Tags: postgresql, join, typeorm, one-to-zero-or-one

I am using node.js typeorm and I have 2 entities with one-to-zero-or-one relation as follows:

```
@Entity('issuer')
export class Issuer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  issuerId: number

  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
  user: User
  
  ...remaining columns...
}

@Entity('user_data')
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false, unique: true })
  email: string

  ...remaining columns...
}
```

A user might be issuer or not, but an issuer certainly is user.

What I am trying to achieve is that without knowing the user type, I want to join 2 tables. For instance considering the following database rows:

```
User  | id | email | 
--------------------
user1 | 1  | xx@xx |
--------------------
user2 | 2  | yy@yy |


Issuer  | issuerId | userId |
----------------------------
issuer1 |    1     |    1   |
```

When I query the email `xx@xx` I want to get:

```
id: 1, email: xx@xx, issuerId: 1
```

When I query the email `yy@yy` I want to get:

```
id: 2, email: yy@yy, issuerId: NULL
```

or it is even ok for issuerId to be dropped if NULL.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_data
LEFT JOIN issuer ON issuer.userId = user_data.id
WHERE user_data.email = $1
```

where $1 is email parameter, but I get the following error:

```
"severity": "ERROR",
"code": "42703",
"hint": "Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"issuer.userId\".",
"file": "parse_relation.c",
"routine": "errorMissingColumn"
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when using camelcase column names, they should be wrapped with double quotes. And also instead of LEFT JOIN, I should have used LEFT OUTER JOIN.

The corrected query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_data
LEFT OUTER JOIN issuer ON issuer."userId" = user_data.id
WHERE user_data.email = $1
```

Comment: If you're designing this DB, you should do yourself a favor and use snake case. Postgres forces everything to lowercase if you do not use identifier quotes. This means anything with capital letters or space in the name (tables, fields, etc.) will **require** identifier quotes. `userid` is not equal to `userId`. Otherwise, over years of using the DB, you'll really wish you chose snake case.

Comment: I just realized that and converted it all to snake case. Do you think I should convert my whole backend into snake case, or only converting the entities should be sufficient? I am using nodejs and it is almost a rule to use camelcase in here.

Comment: Convert everything.

Comment: Yes, anything that is referencing something in the DB or generating DDL should be snake case. Ideally, there would be one interface between your application and the DB. Any functions that wrap DB calls or other internals to your application can use camel case.